# Guacamole stopped working suddenly; problem from guacamole.properties

Tags: postgresql, guacamole

Our Centos 7 AWS Guacamole (version 1.3.0) server was fully working, with postgresql database for the users. One day it decided not to work and I'm perplexed. I didn't set it up and have no access to the person that did.

When logging in to aws.....:8080/guacamole, it comes up with ERROR. If I rename /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties to something else, then it gives the log in screen, so there's some problem with postgres.

[screenshot of error message when trying to access guacamole from web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdCSQ.png)

Here is guacamole.properties:

```
# PostgreSQL properties
postgresql-hostname: localhost
postgresql-port: 5432
postgresql-database: guacamole_db
postgresql-username: guacamole_user
postgresql-password: password
#postgresql-auto-create-accounts: true

#Guac Properties
#skip-if-unavailable: postrgresql
```

guacamole_user does exist, but is not in table `guacamole_entity` and I'm wondering if the user is a postgres user and not a guacamole user, but why would that have changed?
I've tried unhashing `skip-if-unavailable: postgresql` but that didn't change anything.

Also upgraded the postgres java file from `postgresql-42.2.23.jar` to  `postgresql-42.3.1.jar`
but that did nothing.

/var/log/messages doesn't have anything to do with the error. I can't really find a way to debug it.

Totally at a loss, any ideas?

EDIT: It was an SELinux problem. Disabling SELinux solves it, so it's got nothing to do with Postgres. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an SELinux problem. Disabling SELinux solves it, so it's got nothing to do with Postgres. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks of some information. (For example: guacamole version, any other extensions used, error screenshot). If possible, try posting the full version of `/etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties`.

The user specify in `postgresql-username` is a database user (not a guacamole user) so it won't show in `guacamole_entity`.

In order to debug guacamole application, you will have to configure it to show debug log.

1. Create the file `/etc/guacamole/logback.xml`.
2. Insert the following content:

```
<configuration>

    <!-- Appender for debugging -->
    <appender name="GUAC-DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Log at DEBUG level -->
    <!-- For this part, you can change the log level. Log level available: error, warn, info, debug, trace -->
    <!-- by default the level is error -->
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="GUAC-DEBUG"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

3. Restart `guacamole` service.

After setting up, you may start debugging with tomcat logs.
I have not installed in a CentOS before, but in Debian, the default tomcat log path is `/var/lib/tomcat9/logs`.